# Prove $3\left(9-5\sqrt{3}\right) \sum \frac{1}{a} \geqslant \sum a^2+\frac32\cdot\frac{\left[(\sqrt3-2)(ab+bc+ca)+abc\right]^2}{abc}$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

Let $a,\,b,\,c$ are positive real numbers satisfy $a+b+c=3.$ Prove that
$$3\left(9-5\sqrt{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right) \geqslant a^2+b^2+c^2 + \frac32 \cdot \frac{\left[(\sqrt3-2)(ab+bc+ca)+abc\right]^2}{abc}. \quad (1)$$
**Note.** From $(1)$ we get
$$3\left(9-5\sqrt{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right) \geqslant a^2+b^2+c^2.$$
It's was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393792/if-abc-3-show-a2b2c2-leq-27-15-sqrt3-left-frac1a-frac1b).

My solution is write it as SOS
$$\sum \frac{\left[(9-4\sqrt3)c+ab\right](2c+\sqrt3-3)^2(a-b)^2}{24abc} \geqslant 0.$$
Any comments and solutions are welcome and appreciated

Comment: Why down vote ?

Comment: I agree with you , i can't understand why the downvote too, also there is a vote to close this question!.I will upvote to compensate. Possibly the downvoter wanted to know  how you got the SOS

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag Does pqr method work?

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag The SOS solution is nice.

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore Thank you :D

Comment: @River Li I just turned off my PC, I will try with pqr method in the morning

Answer (score 2):

$uvw$ kills this problem!

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$\frac{9(9-5\sqrt3)v^2}{w^3}\geq9u^2-6v^2+\frac{3(w^3-3(2-\sqrt3)v^2)^2}{2w^3}$$ or $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where
$$f(w^3)=6(9-5\sqrt3)u^4v^2-2(3u^2-2v^2)uw^3-3(w^3-3(2-\sqrt3)uv^2)^2.$$
But $$f''(w^3)=-6<0,$$ which says that $f$ is a concave function.

We know that the concave function gets a minimal value for an extreme value of $w^3$,

which by $uvw$ happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

In this case our inequality is obviously true.

2. Two variables are equal.

Let $b=a$ and $c=3-2a$, where $0<a<1.5.$

Thus, we obtain an inequality of one variable, which easy to check.

I got that it's enough to prove: $$(a-1)^2\left(a-\frac{3-\sqrt3}{2}\right)^2(6-2\sqrt3-a)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.